# How to remove app images from gallery

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gallery, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unwanted folders showing up in gallery (bejeweled 2). can they be removed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7866/unwanted-folders-showing-up-in-gallery-bejeweled-2-can-they-be-removed)

I had installed a few application and games, for example beautiful widgets, and several weather widgets etc just to experiment.

After that I have flashed my phone several times, installed different roms, and wiped cache and phone, and did not re-install the apps. But what I see is that the pictures still show up in my phones gallery. How can I remove them.

And how can I make sure files from apps do not show up in my phones gallery app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those apps probably cached the images on the sdcard. You can go though and delete the cache for the applications. Some could be in `/sdcard/android/<package-name>/`, some apps may just create a directory somewhere on the sdcard root.

You can also look at [unwanted folders showing up in gallery (bejeweled 2). can they be removed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7866/unwanted-folders-showing-up-in-gallery-bejeweled-2-can-they-be-removed). It will tell you how to stop images from showing in the gallery, if you still have the application installed.