# How to Ignore the Icons in Camera Album?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, photos, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unwanted folders showing up in Gallery. Can they be removed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7866/unwanted-folders-showing-up-in-gallery-can-they-be-removed)

My Album contains Camera Pics and the icons of other applications. Those icons are there in my SD Card. I took back up of other applications using some Backup applications tool. It stores the icons also. I had to delete them manually to separate the icons and my camera pics.

Is there any way to exclude the icons and include only Camera pics in Album ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get the Gallery and the Music apps to ignore folders on your phone is to create an empty file in the folder called "`.nomedia`".

The easiest way to create that file is to plug your phone into a PC, explore the phone until you can find the folder that has your unwanted icons in it.

Then if you open Windows Notepad, click **File** -> **Save As**, navigate your way to the folder on the phone and then make sure that Notepad's **Save As Type** box says **All Files (*.*)** and does *not* say "Text Documents (*.txt)" you can now type `.nomedia` (note the full stop/period at the start of the file name) and click **Save**.

If you've done it right the file should *not* have a Notepad icon in in Explorer, it should just have a default plain white, rectangular icon. Now safely remove the drive, unplug your phone and (after your phone's done a media scan) the icons should disappear from the gallery.